AWS Cloudwatch Message : Couldn't find key
I have an api key that just stopped working, I have no clue why. I can create a new API key through API Gateway with the same usage plan and that key is authorized. But this key that I have had for a while just does not want to work all of a sudden, I tried through API Gateway's Authorizer Test and testing through postman. Same result: 401 (Unauthorized)
Checking the Authoizer Lambda Cloudwatch Logs I get this response (Only this returns):|
**Couldn't find key **
The Key exists, so any idea what could be happening to cause this error? I was not able to find any resources online mentioning this issue so that is why I am here :)
I have tried to set the key to inactive and reactivate which has no success.
I have tried creating a new key with the same value password but AWS does not allow that.
I have investigating logs further but nothing gave me more info on the exact reason.
